# Android: ImageView that only should display image in one condition, but displays it always

Tags: java, android, imageview

Would anyone be able to notice what's incorrect in this code of mine? As a complete Android noob, I'm trying to use ImageView to display a message and an image ("tryagainimage.png") only if there was no connection. Otherwise, I continue with WebView, and the message and the image should not display in that case.

And this is how I was trying to do this:

In my MainActivity.java, I have these parts:

```
...
private ImageView myImgView;
...
if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ImageView myImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTryAgainImage);
        mImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tryagainimage);
        }
        else {
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
...
```

And here is the part in activity_main.xml:

```
...
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewTryAgainImage"
    android:src="@drawable/tryagainimage"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
...
```

What happens is that without connection, the Toast message appears, and the image is displayed. With the connection, the Toast message does not appear, but the image is still displayed. In a word, the image "tryagainimage" always appears, no matter what. The Toast message, on the other hand, only shows up when needed.

Could anyone notice what I have wrong in the code? Thank you!

Comment: Don`t forget to add permissions: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: What? This is not the issue here...

Answer (score 1):

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

shouldn't it be hidden initially and set it as visible ONLY after you have determined there is no connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

You should set your visibility to gone by default and only turn it on when you have no connection. That is a more logical way to code because having no internet connection is an exception, not in the main flow.

```
...
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewTryAgainImage"
    android:src="@drawable/tryagainimage"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
...
```

to

```
...
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/imageViewTryAgainImage"
     android:src="@drawable/tryagainimage"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
...
```

and in your java code

```
if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ImageView myImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTryAgainImage);
    myImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tryagainimage);
}
else
{
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `else` part

```
myImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You can instantiate the image view only once. You have declared it but I am not sure if you are instantiating it. If you are, then you can remove the redundant instantiations.

Overall it should be

```
ImageView myImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTryAgainImage);

if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //mImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tryagainimage); // This is not required, its already set in xml
    }
    else {
        myImgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ImageView visibility to View.GONE or View.INVISIBLE. I'll recommend you to use View.GONE.

Something like this -

```
if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
    //Your code
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {        
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //Your code
}
```

Another good option is to use TextView with drawableTop. That will let you show the image plus some extra detail about what exactly went wrong so user can fix it if he can.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

That was absolutely the right solution. (For whatever reason,

```
    myImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

kept crashing on the test phone I was using, and I couldn't figure out why, but I tried adapting the solution, and used:

```
            findViewById(R.id.imageViewTryAgainImage).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and then it ran on the phone without errors.)

Thanks!

Comment: Couple of answers say this thing only. Rather than posting it you should have accepted one of the answers.